# python eval assignment error

Tags: django, python-2.7, eval

```
item = Table.objects.get(user_id=user_id)
area_dict ={'grade':'test','name':'name_test'}
s = area_dict['name']+'_grade1'
eval("item."+s+" = area_dict['grade']")
```

I am trying to update the database in python_django, above is the code I want to realize my need, but I meet the error

```
item.name_test = area_dict['grade']
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
                     ^
```

I don't know where I am wrong,can you tell me?

Comment: Why are you using `eval`? Try `setattr(item, s, area_dict['grade'])`.

Comment: Thank you,I just know setattr,it solve my problam!